# Find strings that belong together based on their label

Tags: python, string, list, match

Suppose I have a nested list which looks like this:

```
my_list = [['Germany', 'B-LOC'], ['Angela', 'B-PER'], ['Merkel', 'I-PER']]
```

So each element contains two strings, the first representing a word from text data and the second string represents the label from a machine learning model.

Here, `B-LOC` refers to `Begin Location`, `B-PER` to `Begin Person` and `I-PER` to `Inside Person`.

What I am interested in is a smart way to find strings that belong together, based on their label.

In this case I would like to output something like

```
print(....)
>>> Germany Location
>>> Angela Merkel Person
```

Any suggestion/hint how I could start?

Comment: This is too broad. What have you tried so far? What errors/bad results did you encounter?

Comment: Strings that belongs together. Could you define this? You joined 3 words which have different label, so what is your criterion to group strings?

Comment: If your elements always contain two strings, have you considered using a dictionary for this? like `{'B-LOC': ['Germany',]}` and so on.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking but definitely try f=dict(my_list) and play with the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach. using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_list = [['Germany', 'B-LOC'], ['Angela', 'B-PER'], ['Merkel', 'I-PER']]
d = defaultdict(list)

check_val = {"PER": "Person", "LOC": "Location"}

for i in my_list:
    d[check_val.get(i[1][-3:], "N\A")].append(i[0])

for k, v in d.items():
    print( " ".join(v) + " " + k )
```

**Output:**

```
Angela Merkel Person
Germany Location
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try list comprehension:**

```
data_location = [x[0] for x in my_list if 'LOC' in x[1]]
data_person = [x[0] for x in my_list if 'PER' in x[1]]
print( ' '.join(data_location), 'Location')
print(' '.join(data_person), 'Person')
```

**Output:**

```
Germany Location
Angela Merkel Person
```